# how to limit textView's width according to left width

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, truncate, android-relativelayout

I have a layout (can be relative, linear or constraint)

with TextView aligned to parent left and then ImageView (fix width) aligned that start right to the textView.

I want the image to be rendered first and only then to render the text view.

Meaning I want the text view to be truncated according to the left space after the image was rendered.

```
  <RelativeLayout
      android:id="@+id/account_name_layout"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="0dp"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/account_menu_account_name_layout_bottom_margin">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/account_name"
        style="@style/AccountDataAccountName"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:lines="1"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        tools:text="emailisverylongaswellwewantittogettruncated@gmail.longdomain.com"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/account_name_chevron"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/account_menu_chevron_size"
        android:minWidth="@dimen/account_menu_chevron_size"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/account_menu_chevron_size"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/account_name"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/account_menu_chevron_top_margin"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/account_menu_chevron_left_margin"/>
  </RelativeLayout>
```

I have tried few options:

1) telling the text to be left to the image view

2) putting weight on the text view - made gap between the two elements.

3) setting minWidth to the image view - didn't help just made the imageView scale smaller.

Any idea how to render the image first and how to limit textView's width according to left width?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can force the width on the imageView. That will prevent the textview from pushing it off the space. If you are saying you did this, please post the resulting image as that wouldn't make any sense.

Your above example has no constraints to each other, no enforcement to not overlay or push off. You need some constraints, such as "toTheLeftOf" or "Weight" or LinearLayout to enforce it as Weight only works in LinearLayout.

The easiest way is to just give the imageView a hard coded DP width and height, then set the text to 0 width with a weight of 1 inside a Linear Layout.

You can also use percentages if you want, use a LinearLayout then put a weight sum of like 100 for example (representing 100%). Then assign your image whatever percentage it needs like layout_weight=30 and give the textview 70.

Any of these options will work fine for you. If you try it, and it does not, then post your tried code as it will work unless you are doing something goofy that is not visible in your current example. As I do this all the time, every time you make a row, you typically have an image on the left fixed and text on the right to grow.

Comment: `The easiest way is to just give the imageView a hard coded DP width and height, then set the text to 0 width with a weight of 1 inside a Linear Layout.` Thanks, but then the text and image will be far apart when there is enough space and i want them to be close

Comment: Hi Elad, the text is left aligned, so there would be no space. You could also put a layout wrapper on the textView with weight of 1 to eat up the space and float your gravity of your textview wherever you like. So I'm confused by your response. Please elaborate on what you are trying to accomplish as putting an image with a textbox right next to it, is the solution I provided you. What "space" are you referring to? Maybe you are handling your image incorrectly aka it is not filling the imageView space properly. And you are hoping to float over the imageView unused spaces. That is different.